# How to prevent messages from clogging terminal?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Recently, I have been programming a small game to run in the Linux Terminal. The game involves running an MP3 file from the terminal. However, when this runs using FFMPEG, it sends messages into the terminal. This makes the display difficult to see, and I was wondering if there was a way to shut down those messages without impeding the FFMPEG package. I have tried dmseg -n 1 and other dmseg commands - however, it returned `dmesg: klogctl failed: Operation not permitted`. When I tried to reenable it with `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict`, it returned `-bash: /proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict: Permission denied`. How can I suppress the messages from running the file? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: edit your question to show the simpilest command line that has the problem. Something like `ffmpeg ... options ... file.mp3` should be enough. Then we can help, otherrwise we have to guess. Also `man ffmpeg` and see if there is a `-q` (or `-Q`) option (for quiet). Or maybe using `ffmpeg ...options... file.mp3 2>/dev/null` may solve your problem.

Comment: You write you programmed the game. Do you know how program output and output redirection works? Normal programs hardly ever use `dmesg` output.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg -v quiet` - found by a minute's inspection of the documentation (`man ffmpeg`).

Although I must say that you asked for `ffmpeg` but your hard-to-read screenshot shows `mpg123`